# how to call different function from same form using different submit button in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, submit

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url().'qualified_policy/fetch') ?>
   <?php echo form_input(); ?>
   <?php echo form_submit("btn_add","ADD");?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Above form action is direct to function of a controller. when submit button is clicked it call the fetch function. I want to call another function using another button. then how should be the form action url?

Comment: you can make `condition` for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could using a javascript xml http request and working with ajax. Give a condition of your form what you want to call, and request that form from your main page using get methods

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript function for onclick event where you will change the form action URL dynamically.

Comment: yes, @sarwar, but this is want for my another purpose. it is unable to do this in codeigniter ?